# Apache Kafka data extraction via the .net core API

Tags: .net, apache-kafka

I am using Apache Kafka for fast data write. I am wondering how to connect my solution to .net core API. Is it possible to select messages by key from Kafka? Do I have to put data into the database? For example, my key is the user's email.
I want to set up an API which will have a method of fetching messages by key. Extract data after entering the user's email.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to select messages by key from Kafka?

Not exactly. You can calculate a topic partition, given any key, but that will give all messages in that partition, not only the events for the same key

> I want to set up an API which will have a method of fetching messages by key. Extract data after entering the user's email.

Sounds like an opportunity for KTable (not possible with .net unless you use ksqldb rest api). Otherwise, yes, use a key-value or document-store database

Comment: What do you mean "Otherwise, yes, use a key-value or document-store database"? Should I use some database? I just forgot to write that I can't use Azure or any other cloud. I need to install it on the server "on premise"

Comment: Okay, then install some database server

Comment: Ok. So it's best to do it like this:
* I am sending messages with the key: "email address", value: "name of the purchased product" on Kafka
* Consumer listens to messages and puts records into the database, e.g. MongoDB
* API extracts records from the database

Is this approach fast? Is it better to use a different solution? Is it better to use "ksqldb"?
I want large data to be thrown from various sources and the API can make inquiries to quickly retrieve data for the client.

Comment: Or you can write directly to a database. It's your system, I'm just answering the questions you asked, not here for recommendations on "best" since that's subjective and won't work for all scenarios